# Changing Width of a webpart impact other webpart alignment and page layout in SPS2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, page-layout

Changing width of a WebPart impacts other WebParts.
I`ve 6 WebParts placed in row1.
Changing the width of WebPart 1, impact the other WebPart next to it.
Such that the other WebParts are not align properly anymore on the page.

Please check the explanation via this pic before and after - 
link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzjNm.jpg

Kindly help me, I`ve spent endless amount of time to rectify the issue.

Tried multiple CSS options:

1. Float: left
2. clear: both
3. removing orientation: Horizontal
4. Placing WebPart to different row and trying to align the row next to
   each other.

Nothing so far is working.

Comment: How did you add your webparts? Webpart zone or you have added within html table?

Comment: Webpartzone (default part of Rows) sorry not an exoert when it comes to design section in  sps 2013

Comment: @nagaranjan please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a page layout with these many webpart zones for each webpart, try this option.

1. Create a page using 'Body Only' page layout
2. Edit the page
3. Insert a table in the page content using the Ribbon -> Insert -> Table. Select number of rows and column needed.
4. Once you add the table set the Row height and Column Width in the Table Layout tab. Ribbon -> Table Layout
5. Insert the webparts in the required cells of the table
6. Set height and width of the webpart as required
7. Once the webpart addition and everything is set, go to Design tab in the ribbon and set the table style to 'Table Style 1 - Clear' which will hide the grid lines. So the users will not know there is a table. Ribbon -> Design

Note: Set the Row height and Column Width of the table higher than the Height and Width of the webparts inserted.

Technically, the table size will be fixed and webpart sizes can be adjusted but this also has a limitation as webpart size has to be adjusted according to the table layout.

Hope this may help you. Let me know if any doubt.

Comment: to my understanding going for tables n placing webpart wont a good fit for responsive based design. As i want the content to be visible via mobile n tablets. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: In that case you have to either make the table UI responsive or go with webpart zones.

Comment: that is wat my site has for now. Webpartzones within rows. But not sure wat it tskes to care of the alignment.